# Do OpenCL subbuffers have to be released explicitly even if their parent buffer is released?

Tags: opencl

I am wondering if the release of an OpenCL buffer A that contains subbuffers A1, A2, ... will automatically release also the subbuffers - especially on the host, not the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [specification for `clCreateSubBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateSubBuffer.html) does not cite any exceptions to the general object creation and reference counting rules for sub-buffers. It further states,

> The buffer object returned references the data store allocated for buffer

So I think it's safe to say you need to release each sub-buffer as well as the parent buffer individually, and implementations are free to only release the full parent data store once the last sub-buffer object has been released.

I have certainly not encountered any issues with following this pattern myself.